# How to check if the firewall is enabled in Windows in C

Tags: c, windows, firewall

I would like to check if the firewall is enabled in Windows through C code, I found some methods in C# but only a little bit information from C, How I could do that?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [INetFwProfile interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  . MSDN example of [c++] is available [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Very useful your response, I'm going to try with it

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Windows Firewall API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For Windows XP you read the [`InetFwProfile::FirewallEnabled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365330.aspx). On Vista or later you could use the [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff956124.aspx).